# How to override python pyramid app config settings?

Tags: python, pyramid

I am a newbie at `Python Pyramid` and working on improving an existing app that we have.
I have an app main function defined like below:

```
def web_main(global_config, **settings):
  config = Configurator(settings=settings, root_factory=RootFactory)
  ...
  ...
  config.add_request_method(get_user, "user", reify=True)
  config.set_authentication_policy(authn_policy)
  config.set_authorization_policy(authz_policy)
  ...
  app = config.make_wsgi_app()
  return app
```

I want to override `get_user` request method with my implementation and also want to use my own authentication policy.

With that I was thinking to do write a function like below:

```
def my_web_main(global_config, **settings):
  app = web_main(global_config, **settings)
  <Set Overrides here>
  return app
```

Inside the `config.ini` file I will call `my_web_main` to start this app.

I have not been able to figure out how to set the overrides. Would appreciate some inputs on this.

Comment: Suggest following the example in the [Pyramid SQLAlchemy + URL dispatch wiki tutorial](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/index.html). Also things will change slightly in Pyramid 2.0 which will be released soon, so you might want to get ahead of it on the master branch.

Answer (score 1):

The configurator is where you should perform overrides. So the answer is to modify web_main or define your own. Pyramid has an override mechanism via `config.include()`, but it does not work one level higher where you're attempting to override things with a built wsgi-app. You have to do it at the config level.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote my own main method like you said